# Used-to structure

Tags: exam-questions

I've recently come across Reading and Use of English task (part 4). 
Rewrite sentence `I always hated pasta when I was a child but now I cook it regularly` using word **USE**. 
 
My answer is (in italic my completing structure): I *did use to hate* pasta when I was a child but now I cook it regularly. 
Answer key says the missing structure is: *didn't use to like/enjoy*. 
 
Is my answer correct grammatically and lexically? Or is it weird?

Comment: The answer key is correct for most contexts. Why do you want to use emphatic "did?

Comment: The thing is I want to avoid negative statement and want to know if my answer sustain the same level of flexibility like answer key's

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a negative statement, I'd write:

> I **used** to hate pasta when I was a child but now I cook it regularly.

So, if nobody requires that you use the word "use" in this exact form, you can use "used." "Did use" is also grammatically correct, but it's usually used to additionally emphasize the statement.

Comment: The thing is, according to CAE requirements in part 4, you cannot change the word given...

Comment: @AndrewBumetsov, are you sure, using "used" instead of "use" would be considered a change? Also, is this some actual test when someone will evaluate it later?

Comment: Unfortunately, Cambridge says using "used" instead of "use" is a change. Do you imply an examiner will give it a chance?

Comment: @AndrewBumetsov, yes, I'm asking if this task involves some official judgement by someone - as to be correct or wrong? Both your suggestion in the question and the one in my answer are grammatically correct, though.

Comment: If "use" needs to be used exactly like this, then I don't see any other option than "I did use to hate", because the suggestion "I didn't use to like" is the _change_ of the meaning of the sentence (hate and didn't like are not exactly the same.) But I think, "I did use to hate" sounds forced in this context. I used to hate sounds much more usual.